# Remove “/ent/” subfolder with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I used to publish my website from a subfolder but it's now moved to root. The problem is that I have a lot of links with the subfolder "/ent/" included in the url.

Some urls also have index.php included, if someone could help to get rid of that to it would be great!.

Example: `http://www.myurl.com/ent/index`

Example: `http://www.myurl.com/ent/index.php/index`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ent/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```